# Using Hibernate to CREATE SCHEMA in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

All i want is to execute the following SQL on my PostgreSQL server after my Hibernate SessionFactory has been initialized:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "fooschema" AUTHORIZATION "foouser";
```

Currently I am using the following routine:

```
Session s      = factory.withOptions().openSession();
SQLQuery query = s.createSQLQuery(sql);
int res        = query.executeUpdate();
// res is 0 and the schema has NOT been created
s.flush();
s.disconnect();
s.close();
```

The connected user has the permissions to chreate new schemata. So this is a simple question:
What am i doing wrong?

**Attachments:**

Turning hibernate show_sql on prints the following:

```
Hibernate:
    CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "fooschema" AUTHORIZATION "foouser";
```

Comment: What is the error message? Btw: stuff like that is better done using proper (versioned!) DDL scripts.

Comment: There is no error message.

Comment: I don't see a commit in there. Maybe that's the problem? And if you are already using Liquibase, why don't you put this into the liquibase change set?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i think creating schema cannot be reverted (its executed immidiatly) so commit ist necessary

Comment: You are right ... The solution is to put the query in a transaction.

Comment: There are only very few DDL statements that are non-transactional in Postgres. `CREATE SCHEMA` definitely needs a commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem (Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name)

```
Session s      = factory.withOptions().openSession();
Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
SQLQuery query = s.createSQLQuery(sql);
int res        = query.executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting property

```
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

in hibernate config

Comment: Does that also create the *schema*? I though it would only create the tables.

Comment: I am not using hbm2ddl.auto. I just wanted to create the schema for liquibase, which actually creates the tables.

Comment: @vralfy can you turn on hibernate.show_sql to true and show what is logged to console when you execute this sql ?

Comment: @smajlo attached it above

Comment: @vralfy its silly by maybe schema is already created so thats why you getting 0 in return ?

Comment: No, it seems the result is always 0. But i've found the solution. Thanks anyway